# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuse'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I have set up a GPU Jupyter Notebook VM using the AI platform on Google Cloud. The server runs Debian stretch.

I want to mount a bucket I've created called `example` onto a folder called `/home/jupyter/transfer`. I've been following the instructions outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using_feat_name) but when I run `gsfuse example /home/jupyter/transfer` I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuse'
```

I've installed `fuse` with:

`sudo apt-get install fuse`

which is successful but the `gsfuse` code still doesn't run. I then installed the pip package with:

`pip install fuse-python`

And it still wouldn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I managed to figure this out. The problem was the python package and where I was installing it.

If you do:

```
sudo apt-get install fuse
pip install -U fusepy --user
gsfuse example /home/jupyter/transfer --background
```

It'll work (where `--background`) runs the mount in the backgroud.